# If I just construct data with pure haskell type, what does that mean?

Tags: haskell, types, constructor

```
    data Number = Int | Float deriving(Eq,Ord)
```

What does Int and Float mean here? A constructor or a haskell type?

And how is Bool defined in haskell?
LYAH says

> We can think Bool implemented like this:
>
> ```
>    data Bool = False | True deriving (Ord)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
data Number = Int | Float deriving(Eq,Ord)
```

In the above `Int` and `Float` are just constructors.  They have nothing to do with the `Int` or `Float` types that can take on values such as `1`, or `42`.

```
Prelude> data Number = Int | Float deriving (Show)
Prelude> Int
Int
Prelude> :type Int
Int :: Number
Prelude> Float
Float
Prelude> :type Float
Float :: Number
```

If you wanted, you could add fields to these constructors so they can carry Int and Float types inside:

```
Prelude> data Number' = Int' Int | Float' Float deriving (Show)
Prelude> :type Int'
Int' :: Int -> Number'
Prelude> :type Int' 494
Int' 494 :: Number'
Prelude> Int' 42
Int' 42
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Do you know how the Bool is implemented in haskell?

Comment: @user5963064 see my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

For the `Bool` part: you can just ask GHCi:

```
λ> :i Bool
data Bool = False | True
    -- Defined in `ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Types'
```

so yes - it's indeed defined like this ;)

(sorry about the comment-like answer - it might be borderline - just let me know and I move/delete)

---

BTW: you can indeed find the [Source on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Types.html#Bool):

```
module GHC.Types

...

data {-# CTYPE "HsBool" #-} Bool = False | True
```

Comment: That source is stripped out with CPP `#if 0`. `Bool` is actually defined in [GHC.Types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Types.html#Bool). Of course, it should never be imported from such a low-level internal module!

Comment: @dfeuer ... yes sorry (should have wondered about the GHCi claim) - I guess the definition still stands